# Magento 2 : How to add Custom link product Attribute in Custom product link grid

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, magento2.2.2

I have added new custom product link type and it working fine.
I want to add s**ome custom attribute to it grid** and **in grid i want to give text box option for enter custom attribute value** and when product save at that time i want to **save** it.

https://prnt.sc/i2i61b

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi,

How did you manage to add new product link type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finnaly i got solution

I overide **Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Related.php**

di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
         <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Related"
                        type="Test\TestRelation\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Related"/>
</config>
enter code here
```

Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Related.php
**In this file i override fillMeta() function**

```
  /**
         * Retrieve meta column
         *
         * @return array
         * @since 101.0.0
         */
        protected function fillMeta() {
            return [
                'id' => $this->getTextColumn('id', false, __('ID'), 0),
                'thumbnail' => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                                'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/dynamic-rows/cells/thumbnail',
                                'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                                'dataScope' => 'thumbnail',
                                'fit' => true,
                                'label' => __('Thumbnail'),
                                'sortOrder' => 10,
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'name' => $this->getTextColumn('name', false, __('Name'), 20),
                'status' => $this->getTextColumn('status', true, __('Status'), 30),
                'attribute_set' => $this->getTextColumn('attribute_set', false, __('Attribute Set'), 40),
                'sku' => $this->getTextColumn('sku', true, __('SKU'), 50),
                'price' => $this->getTextColumn('price', true, __('Price'), 60),
                'actionDelete' => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'additionalClasses' => 'data-grid-actions-cell',
                                'componentType' => 'actionDelete',
                                'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                                'label' => __('Actions'),
                                'sortOrder' => 70,
                                'fit' => true,
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'position' => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'dataType' => Number::NAME,
                                'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                                'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                                'dataScope' => 'position',
                                'sortOrder' => 80,
                                'visible' => false,
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'sidea' => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'dataType' => Number::NAME,
                                'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                                'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                                'label' => __('Side A'),
                                'sortOrder' => 80,
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'sideb' => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'dataType' => Number::NAME,
                                'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                                'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                                'label' => __('Side B'),
                                'sortOrder' => 90,
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'sidec' => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'dataType' => Number::NAME,
                                'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                                'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                                'label' => __('Side C'),
                                'sortOrder' => 100,
                                'editorConfig' => ['editorType' => 'text']
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'sided' => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'dataType' => Number::NAME,
                                'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                                'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                                'label' => __('Side D'),
                                'sortOrder' => 110,
                                'editorConfig' => ['editorType' => 'text']
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ];
        }
```

For Add Editor Option,
In Cross Sell etc or Custom Product Link option

Need to set **editorConfig** property of column so it display Text Box,

**'editorConfig' => ['editorType' => 'text']**

Comment: were you able to save this value?

Answer (score 0):

@Navin How were you able to save this value? I've been trying to create a new catalog_product_link_attribute, but have been out of luck. Any idea?